# How patch a method being called from an instance in python

Tags: python, mocking, monkeypatching, magicmock

I am trying to write a unittest for my file **abc.py**. 
I am not able to set a return value for a method being called from a class instance.

Here is my file:

**abc.py**

```
class ABC(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fetch_id(self):
        id = # from somewhere
        return id

def main():
    module = someRandomClass()
    client = ABC()
    account_id = client.fetch_id()
    module.save(account_id=account_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is the test file

**test.py**

```
import mock
import abc

@mock.patch('abc.ABC')
@mock.patch('someRandomClass')
def test_all(module, mock_abc):
    abc.main()
    module.assert_called_with()

    client = mock_abc.return_value
    mock_abc.assert_called_with()

    client.fetch_id.return_value = '12345667'
    module.save.assert_called_with(account_id='12345667')
```

Getting the following error:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: save(account_id='12345667')
Actual call: save(account_id=<MagicMock name='ABC().fetch_id()' id='4507253008'>)
```

Comment: Did you try to create object instead of use this mock method?
Just to test .. Does your class ABC work

Comment: This is just a snippet from my actual class to give readers an idea of my code structure.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the functions need to be set before `abc.main()` is called.

```
import mock
import abc

@mock.patch('abc.ABC')
@mock.patch('someRandomClass')
def test_all(module, mock_abc):
    client = mock_abc.return_value
    client.fetch_id.return_value = '12345667'
    abc.main()
    module.assert_called_with()

    mock_abc.assert_called_with()

    module.save.assert_called_with(account_id='12345667')
```

Comment: what is `mock_abc`? Where does it come from?